# How to get unique result in ElasticSearch Result?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am trying to get elastic search unique results but it does not work for me.

I have tried using 'terms aggregation' as below.

```
$searchQuery['body']['aggregations']['my_field'] = ['terms' => ['field' => 'my_field', 'size' => 500]];
```

If anyone has an idea please let me know about this.